# How can I get an account name from a given public key?

Tags: eosjs

is there any way to get the name for a given public key, something like?

```
      eos.getKeyAccounts({
        "public_key": "EOS73iTgPXEPXGazpU6XzU5Vq81Qk7TUHsmujTYn9DKJHm4MX1e2j"
      })
```

Am I reading this wrong or is it out of date? https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-api/blob/master/src/api/v1/history.json#L32

When I call the function with no arguments i get this back

```
USAGE
getKeyAccounts - undefined

PARAMETERS
{
  "public_key": "public_key_type"
}

RETURNS
{
  "account_names": "account_name[]"
}

ERRORS
nothing special
```

the error I get is

```
api error =>  https://api.eosrio.io/v1/chain/get_account {"account_name":"EOS73iTgPXEPXGazpU6XzU5Vq81Qk7TUHsmujTYn9DKJHm4MX1e2j"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong address. It should be

```
https://api.eosnewyork.io/v1/history/get_key_accounts
```

with POST data:

```
{"public_key":"EOS73iTgPXEPXGazpU6XzU5Vq81Qk7TUHsmujTYn9DKJHm4MX1e2j"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to use a command line solution, you can try:

```
$ cleos -u http://api.eosnewyork.io  get accounts <public key>
```

This will return all the accounts associated with a public key.